# Rails caxlsx - align document right to left

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-6, right-to-left, axlsx

I'm using [caxlsx](https://github.com/caxlsx/caxlsx) with rails 6 and I can't find a way to set it to output the document as right to left (the document is in Hebrew).
Does anyone know how to set it?

Thanks!

Jordan.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After digging into the source code of the gem, I finally managed to figure out this line is needed at the end of the view file (export.xlsx.axlsx in my case):

```
sheet.sheet_view.right_to_left = true
```